Why is my Task Title and Task Desc not updating the text after I click the edit button?
When I click the edit button after inputting the task title and task desc in the form, it returns "No Title and No Description." in the console, it returns an empty string.  Whereas the priority and due updates.
So I click the div that displays the added task details to edit it.
What I expect to happen:

The task details: (Task Title, Task Desc, Due Date, Priority) will change once I hit the edit button

What actually happend:

The Due Date and Priority changed. The Task Title and Task Description did not and displayed "No Title" & "No Description"

Form module:
import { Due } from "./due";
import { Task } from './task';
import { addTask } from "./taskStorage";
import { createPriorityDropdown } from './prioritylist';
import taskpage from "./taskpage";
import flatpickr from "flatpickr";
import { showTaskModal } from "./modal";
import { updateTaskInStorage } from "./updateTaskInStorage"
    
export default function showForm(task) {
  // the rest of the code
    
  const titleInput = document.createElement('input');
  titleInput.type = 'text';
  titleInput.id = 'titleInput';
  titleInput.placeholder = 'Task Name';
  titleInput.required = true;
  titleInput.value = task ? task.task_name : '';
  minicontainer.appendChild(titleInput);
    
  const descInput = document.createElement('input');
  descInput.type = 'text';
  descInput.id = 'descInput';
  descInput.placeholder = 'Task Description';
  descInput.required = true;
  descInput.value = task ? task.task_desc : '';
  minicontainer.appendChild(descInput);
    
  form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const task_name = document.getElementById('titleInput').value;
    const task_desc = document.getElementById('descInput').value;
    const task_priority_value = task_priority.textContent !== 'Priority' ?     task_priority.textContent : null;
    const task_dueDate = document.getElementById('dueDateInput').value;
    
    console.log('Task name:', task_name);  
    console.log('Task description:', task_desc);  
    
    // the rest of the code
    
    if (task) {
      console.log('Task being edited:', task);
      const updatedTask = new Task(task.id, task_name, task_desc, task_priority_value, new Due(task_dueDate));
      console.log('Updated task:', updatedTask);
      updateTaskInStorage(updatedTask);
      displayTask(updatedTask);
    } else {
      const newTask = new Task(null, task_name, task_desc, task_priority_value, new Due(task_dueDate));
      addTask(newTask);
      displayTask(newTask);
    }
  });
    
  function displayTask(task) {
    const choosetask_container = document.querySelector('.task_containerdisplay');
    
    let taskElement = choosetask_container.querySelector(`[data-id="${task.id}"]`);
    
    if (!taskElement) {
      taskElement = document.createElement('div');
      taskElement.classList.add('task');
      taskElement.setAttribute('data-id', task.id); 
      choosetask_container.appendChild(taskElement);
    } else {
      // Clear the existing content before updating
      taskElement.innerHTML = '';
    }
    
    const taskcheckcontainer = document.createElement('div');
    taskcheckcontainer.classList.add('checker');
    taskElement.appendChild(taskcheckcontainer);
    
    const checkBox = document.createElement('input');
    checkBox.type = 'checkbox';
    taskcheckcontainer.appendChild(checkBox);
    
    checkBox.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      event.stopPropagation();
      if (checkBox.checked) {
        choosetask_container.removeChild(taskElement);
      }
    })
    
    const taskName = document.createElement('p');
    taskName.classList.add('taskName');
    taskName.textContent = task.task_name ? task.task_name : "No Title";
    taskcheckcontainer.appendChild(taskName);
    
    const taskDesc = document.createElement('p');
    taskDesc.classList.add('taskDesc');
    taskDesc.textContent = task.task_desc ? task.task_desc : "No Description";
    taskElement.appendChild(taskDesc);
    
    // rest of the code
    
    taskElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
      showTaskModal(task);
    });
    
    choosetask_container.appendChild(taskElement);
  }

